# Does session secret in nodejs does same thing as signed cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

In express you setup session kinda like this:

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: store({...}),
  secret: 'topsecret'
}));
```

On reading up what `secret` does, 
I got this: `protects against session hijacking by checking the fingerprint`

which sounds very much like signed cookie : `ensure that a value has not been tampered with. It's placed in a different object (req.signedCookies) to differentiate between the two`

Is there a difference between two?

I understand signed cookie, hash is created with cookie value + secret and saved along values in cookie. This way you know if cookie values have been tampered with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the secret is used to sign the cookie so it can't be tampered. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js) on how express session serialises the cookie:

```
function setcookie(res, name, val, secret, options) {
  var signed = 's:' + signature.sign(val, secret);
  var data = cookie.serialize(name, signed, options);

  debug('set-cookie %s', data);

  var prev = res.getHeader('set-cookie') || [];
  var header = Array.isArray(prev) ? prev.concat(data) : [prev, data];

  res.setHeader('set-cookie', header)
}
```

Basically is signing it using a `SHA-256`, which generates a 32 byte hash.

There is also `unsigncookie` which verifies your cookie hasn't been tampered. Obviously it verifies against the same secret above used to sign it:

```
function unsigncookie(val, secrets) {
  for (var i = 0; i < secrets.length; i++) {
    var result = signature.unsign(val, secrets[i]);

    if (result !== false) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I found this as well: 
`Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, however
cookies are used, so we must use the cookieParser().......secret session cookie is signed with this secret to prevent tampering`

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html#session

Comment: Ah yep - I always find easier to drill in the source in these cases ...

Comment: for me looking at lot of code makes me = @_@ , having someone explicitly say in words is reassuring.